# NHibernate (Unable to locate class)

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have the next code:

```
IUnitOfWork factory = DI.Get<IUnitOfWork>();
ISession session = (ISession)ReflectionUtils.GetPropertyValue(factory, "Session");
IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("SELECT new Model.TestClass(FechaCreacion,Demora) from Pedido");
TestClass[] _list = query.List<TestClass>().ToArray();

public class TestClass
{
    public DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }
    public int Demora { get; set; }
}
```

I need to return a list of my objects to show them in a datagridview, but i'm gettin the next exception :

```
NHibernate.QueryException was unhandled
  Message=Unable to locate class [Model.TestClass] [SELECT new Model.TestClass(FechaCreacion,Demora) from Pedido]
  Source=NHibernate
  QueryString=SELECT new Model.TestClass(FechaCreacion,Demora) from Pedido
  StackTrace:
       en NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.ConstructorNode.ResolveConstructor(String path) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\Tree\ConstructorNode.cs:línea 151
       en NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.ConstructorNode.Prepare() en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\Tree\ConstructorNode.cs:línea 112
       en NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.ProcessConstructor(IASTNode constructor) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\HqlSqlWalker.cs:línea 540
       en NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.selectExpr() en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\Generated\HqlSqlWalker.cs:línea 2761
       en NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.selectExprList() en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\Generated\HqlSqlWalker.cs:línea 2397
       en NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.selectClause() en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\Generated\HqlSqlWalker.cs:línea 2272
       en NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.unionedQuery() en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\Generated\HqlSqlWalker.cs:línea 1664
       en NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.query() en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\Generated\HqlSqlWalker.cs:línea 1510
       en NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.selectStatement() en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\Generated\HqlSqlWalker.cs:línea 536
       en NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.statement() en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\Generated\HqlSqlWalker.cs:línea 435
       en NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlTranslator.Translate() en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\QueryTranslatorImpl.cs:línea 590
       en NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.Analyze(String collectionRole) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\QueryTranslatorImpl.cs:línea 449
       en NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.DoCompile(IDictionary`2 replacements, Boolean shallow, String collectionRole) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\QueryTranslatorImpl.cs:línea 387
       en NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.Compile(IDictionary`2 replacements, Boolean shallow) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\QueryTranslatorImpl.cs:línea 71
       en NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IASTNode ast, String queryIdentifier, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.cs:línea 43
       en NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String queryString, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.cs:línea 21
       en NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLStringQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(String hql, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\Query\HQLStringQueryPlan.cs:línea 24
       en NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLStringQueryPlan..ctor(String hql, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\Query\HQLStringQueryPlan.cs:línea 16
       en NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLStringQueryPlan..ctor(String hql, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\Query\HQLStringQueryPlan.cs:línea 10
       en NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(String queryString, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\Query\QueryPlanCache.cs:línea 61
       en NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(String query, Boolean shallow) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\AbstractSessionImpl.cs:línea 304
       en NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(String queryString) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\AbstractSessionImpl.cs:línea 283
       en Services.Services.Implementation.PedidoServiceImpl.ConsultaEsperaXCocinaYBarra() en C:\Repositorio\ProyectosCasinoClub\SPMontaPlatosOK\Code\Services\Services\Implementation\PedidoServiceImpl.cs:línea 124
       en View.Frm_Consultas.btn_recuperar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) en C:\Repositorio\ProyectosCasinoClub\SPMontaPlatosOK\Code\View\Frm_Consultas.cs:línea 52
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       en ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       en ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonButton.OnButtonClick(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
       en ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.ButtonController.OnClick(MouseEventArgs e)
       en ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.ButtonController.MouseUp(Control c, Point pt, MouseButtons button)
       en ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.ViewBase.MouseUp(Point pt, MouseButtons button)
       en ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.ViewBase.MouseUp(Point pt, MouseButtons button)
       en ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.ViewBase.MouseUp(Point pt, MouseButtons button)
       en ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.ViewBase.MouseUp(Point pt, MouseButtons button)
       en ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.ViewManager.MouseUp(MouseEventArgs e, Point rawPt)
       en ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.VisualControlBase.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       en ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.VisualControlBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       en System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       en System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       en SPMontaPlatos.Program.<LoadApp>c__Binding.Invoke(Object& instance, Arguments arguments, Object aspectArgs) en C:\Repositorio\ProyectosCasinoClub\SPMontaPlatosOK\Code\SPMontaPlatos\Program.cs:línea 85
       en PostSharp.Aspects.Internals.MethodInterceptionArgsImpl.Proceed()
       en SPMontaPlatos.Aspects.Login.OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args) en C:\Repositorio\ProyectosCasinoClub\SPMontaPlatosOK\Code\SPMontaPlatos\Aspects\Login.cs:línea 30
       en SPMontaPlatos.Program.LoadApp() en C:\Repositorio\ProyectosCasinoClub\SPMontaPlatosOK\Code\SPMontaPlatos\Program.cs:línea 83
       en SPMontaPlatos.Program.Main() en C:\Repositorio\ProyectosCasinoClub\SPMontaPlatosOK\Code\SPMontaPlatos\Program.cs:línea 31
       en System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       en System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       en Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       en System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       en System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.TypeLoadException
       Message=Could not load type Model.TestClass. Possible cause: no assembly name specified.
       Source=NHibernate
       TypeName=""
       StackTrace:
            en NHibernate.Util.ReflectHelper.TypeFromAssembly(AssemblyQualifiedTypeName name, Boolean throwOnError) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Util\ReflectHelper.cs:línea 291
            en NHibernate.Util.ReflectHelper.ClassForName(String name) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Util\ReflectHelper.cs:línea 181
            en NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.ConstructorNode.ResolveConstructor(String path) en d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\Tree\ConstructorNode.cs:línea 146
       InnerException:
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me, sorry for my very basic english.

Comment: Have you made sure that `TestClass` is indeed declared inside a namespace named `Model`? Is that assembly referenced?

Comment: Yes Daniel, the namespace is correct and the assembly is referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding something like this in your hbm file:

```
<import class="NH.Domain.DTOs.ProductDTO, NH.Domain" />
```

Here is the full explanation:

http://gustavoringel.blogspot.com/2009/02/creating-dto-in-nhibernate-hql-using.html